# Connect with SSH

Tags: ssh, server, connection

I just got my raspberry but I don't have a monitor and a keyboard, so I want to be using my raspberry for a webcrawler/some kind of a server/backup. My question is:

How can I use it through my linux laptop via SSH or something else ?

using the newest raspberry pi b+
How is it connected to the rest of your LAN?- With Ethernet
Have you tried a search for headless Pi (either here or on the web)? – no

Comment: Are you looking for something other than "Yes."?

Comment: -1 for no effort on your part. What model Pi are you using? How is it connected to the rest of your LAN? Have you tried a search for headless Pi (either here or on the web)?

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: What distro are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is quite timely.

The way SSH works by default has changed in the 25th November 2016 release of Jessie (lite and full) and NOOBS.

The SSH server is no longer enabled by default.

To enable the SSH server you need to create a file called ssh in the boot directory.  The boot directory is the FAT formatted directory visible in windows.

Nothing needs to be in the file.  The presence of the file is all that is needed.

Comment: Where is that boot directory placed? Does that mean that I have to install some kind of OS first and if so does that mean that I can't ssh without having installed something with a monitor and a keyboard ?

Comment: Without a bootable SD card in the SD card slot the Pi is a useless collection of plastics and metal.  You need to have written an image to the SD card.  If you insert the written SD card into a reader connected to a Windows PC there will be one directory visible (with files such as config,txt and cmdline.txt).  You create a file called ssh in that directory.

Comment: I have a SD card which has NOOBS on it it has 2 folders one is called overlays and the other is System Volume Information

Comment: I'm afraid all I know about NOOBS is that it exists.  I have not used it.  The overlays folder doesn't sound right so I'd create the file in the System Volume Information folder.

Comment: @Harton Noobs can't be setup the first time headless. You are going to need to either get a keyboard and monitor or download Raspbain and flash it to your SD card.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the answer provided by joan (and because I am a new user who cannot upvote, or even add a comment without reputation), here is an article from raspberrypi.org explaining the reasoning for changing SSH recently. Hope this helps!

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/